# Taxonomy view page doesn't show terms with parents

Tags: taxonomy

I'm using a script that inserts a lot of terms at once. It always has a parent and child term and checks if they exists and add them. The problem now is that the term urls don't work and the taxonomy page only shows the parents unless I save a term or add a new one. It doesn't seem to involve transients and the three taxonomy tables are unchanged.

```
$parent = term_exists( $columns['B'], 'custom_tax' );
if ( $parent == 0 || $parent == null ) {
     $parent = wp_insert_term( $columns['B'], 'custom_tax', array( 'description' => $columns['A'] ) );
}

$child = term_exists( $columns['D'], 'custom_tax', $parent['term_id'] );
if ( $child == 0 || $child == null ) {
     $child = wp_insert_term( $columns['D'], 'custom_tax', array( 'parent' => $parent['term_id'], 'description' => $columns['C'] ) );
}

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, array( $child['term_id'] ), 'custom_tax' );
```

Comment: From description seems like might be same issue as http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42311/child-terms-not-displaying-on-the-taxonomy-term-admin-screen

Comment: Correct. The solution was delete_option( "{$taxonomy}_children" );. What you can find on a response on that question.